# Why can't a std::num::ParseIntError be converted into Box<dyn std::error::Error>?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to parse a string into an integer, and propagate parse errors up with `?` inside a function returning `Result<_, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`. However, it doesn't seem like the compiler can convert from a `ParseIntError` into the necessary `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`:

```rust
let res: Result<u32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = "0".parse::<u32>();
         ---------------------------------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found struct `ParseIntError`

expected enum `std::result::Result<_, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`
found enum `std::result::Result<_, ParseIntError>`
```

However, I believe this should work because:

- a `std::error::Error` can be converted to a `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` using this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E
- a `std::num::ParseIntError` can be converted to an `std::error::Error` because `Error` is automatically implemented on `Debug + Display` which `ParseIntError` implements both of

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, it doesn't seem like the compiler can convert from a `ParseIntError` into the necessary `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`:

Rust does not do that conversion automatically. Your https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E link is correct, but nothing in your code will cause that function to run.

This code would need to use `.map_err(|e| e.into());` or `.map_err(From::from);` to map the `ParseIntError` into your target `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` type. e.g.

```
let res: Result<u32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = "0".parse::<u32>().map_err(|e| e.into());
```

Rust generally does not implicitly transform the types of values except for a select few cases. For instance if you were to instead use a function returning `Result<u32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`, then `"0".parse::<u32>()?` (note the questionmark at the end) would automatically use `From::from`.